# React Native Restyle by shopify

Tags: react-native, styles, restyle

Is there a way to access colours outside of components?  It appears that any access to the styles is through hooks.  I am using react-native-snackbar that accepts colours but runs through my middle ware so doesn't have any access to a component.

Answer (score 1):

You can import `theme`.

```
import theme from './theme';
const { colors } = theme;
```

The `theme` object is [created](https://github.com/Shopify/restyle#defining-your-theme) as -

```
export const theme = createTheme({ ... })
```

Comment: is it possible to know which theme im on?  Similar to how i18n can access which language outside of components?

Comment: Outside components there is no straightforward way. The `useTheme` hook is the standard way to access the theme object. But it can't be used in non-react components. You might need to store the current theme name somewhere if there are multiple themes.